# Getting the right data of arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, select

just a simple question, how can we get the name of the category "Meat" by accessing the array tags? Because I know how to get if the category is the array name, or if doing it by the array index. So again, my question is to select name where category is juice from tags array and doing this without array indexing.

So,
category Juice will return the name (Apple) and category Meat will return Beef!

Thanks heaps

```
    "tags":[  
                {  
                   "internal_name":"Apple_Juice",
                   "name":"Apple Juice",
                   "category":"Juice",
                },
                {  
                   "internal_name":"Beef",
                   "name":"Beef",
                   "category":"Meat",
                },
]
```

Comment: so you get an array of categories and you want to filter it? did you look into array_filter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function get_name($catName, $data){ //$data = your json data
   $name = '';
   $data = json_decode($data);
   foreach($data as $item){
      if($item->category == $catName){
         $name = $item->internal_name;
         break;
      }
   }
  return $name;
}
```

Comment: Wow If totally slipped off my mind! Thanks heaps dude